# Relationship between Naive Bayes and MLE

Tags: maximum-likelihood, naive-bayes

I have found various references describing Naive Bayes and they all demonstrated that it used MLE for the calculation. However, this is my understanding:

$P(y=c|x)$ $\propto$ $P(x|y=c)P(y=c)$

with $c$ is the class the model may classify $y$ as.

And that's all, we can infer $P(x|y=c)$ and $P(c)$ from the data. I don't see where the MLE shows its role.

Answer (score 1):

The relationship is that the overall model is Naive Bayes, but there is an MLE estimate for parameters in this model. We have two kinds of parameters in a Naive Bayes model: $q(y)$ and $q_j(x_j|y)$ in the model $$p(y, x_1, \dots, x_d) = q(y)\prod q_j(x_j|y)$$ and each of them have an MLE given by $\hat{q(y)} = \frac{\text{count}(y)}{n}$ and $\hat{q_j} = \frac{\text{count}_j(x|y)}{\text{count(y)}}$.

More details can be found in these [lecture notes](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/%7Emcollins/em.pdf).